# How to snapshot a queue to avoid infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a ConcurrentLinkedQueue that allow insertion from multiple thread however when I poll the queue, I do it in one function and I poll until the queue is empty. This can lead to an infinite loop because there can be thread inserting to the queue while I am polling.
How can I create a view of the queue and empty it before polling and still be thread safe?

Comment: I think an Iterator is what you're looking for.

Comment: @NAMS Concurrent iterators are weakly consistent; although it guarantees what is seen at the time of construction is the view of the collection at that time, elements may leak in as you iterate, if you have a 100% update every addition, you're back to where we started.

Comment: Why do you have to pull everything off the queue until it's empty?  You can do something like get the number of elements in the queue before you start pulling items off, and only pull that many items at most.  Or you can pull one and immediately process it.

Comment: You also have a much bigger problem.  If your one thread that's pulling items off the queue can't pull items off faster than they're put on the queue, there's no way you'll ever be able to actually *do* anything with all the items put on the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I see is to use a [`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) and iterating until you reach the most recently added item. You cannot do this with a single ended queue because reads look at the head first and you will need to read the tail in order to find the last added element.

The way that `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` works is that calls to `offer(Object)` and `add(Object)` will place the item at the tail of the queue. Calls to `poll()` will read the head of the queue, like so:

```
// Read direction --->
HEAD -> E1 -> E2 -> E3 = TAIL
// Write direction --->
```

As you add more items, the tail will extend to the last element, but since we want to empty the queue as we last saw it, we will grab the tail pointer and iterate until we reach the tail. We can then let subsequent iterations deal with what was added whilst we empty the queue. We `peek` first because using `poll` will remove the last added value and thus we would not be able to determine when to stop removing the elements because our marker gets removed.

```
ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Object> deque = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

public void emptyCurrentView() {
    Object tail = deque.peekLast();
    if (tail != null) {
        while (true) {
            // Poll the current head
            Object current = deque.poll();

            // Process the element
            process(current);

            // If we finish processing the marker
            // Exit the method
            if (current == tail) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You do not need to modify the producer code as the producer's default `offer(Object)` and `add(Object)` do exactly the same thing as adding the element to the tail.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a view of the queue and empty it before polling and still be thread safe?

Yeah this sounds like a really bad pattern.  The whole point of using a concurrent queue implementation is that you can add to and remove from the queue at the same time.  If you want to stick with `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` then I'd just do something like this:

```
// run every so often
while (true) {
    // returns null immediately if the queue is empty
    Item item = blockingQueue.poll();
    if (item == null) {
       break;
    }
    // process the item...
}
```

However, I would consider switching to use `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead, because it supports `take()`.  The consumer thread would be in a loop like this:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Item> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
...
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // wait for the queue to get an item
    Item item = blockingQueue.take();
    // process item...
}
```

`BlockingQueue` extends `Queue` so the `poll()` loop is also available.